# Not unique table/alias: 'request

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the  following query in my application,

```
$que="SELECT DISTINCT prescription.commodity_name, prescription.dosage, prescription.duration, prescription.prescription_id, prescription.remarks, prescription.paid, employee.f_name, prescription.quantity_requested, employee.s_name, employee.other_name, prescription.doctor_id, request.strength,  stock.unit_per_pack, stock.selling_price, stock.buying_price
FROM prescription
INNER JOIN request ON prescription.medname = request.commodity_name
INNER JOIN stock ON stock.stock_id = request.stock_id
INNER JOIN request ON request.request_id = transaction.transaction_id
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.employee_id = prescription.doctor_id
INNER JOIN visit ON prescription.visit_id = visit.visit_id
WHERE prescription.visit_id =  '".$id."'";
```

When I run the script file , I get the following data error : Not unique table/alias: 'request

How can I solve this problem Or what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: give it a unique table alias

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two joins on `request` this means, for example, when you `SELECT request.strength` MySQL doesn't know which table to use.

Consider adding an alias:

```
SELECT DISTINCT prescription.commodity_name, prescription.dosage, prescription.duration, prescription.prescription_id, prescription.remarks, prescription.paid, employee.f_name, prescription.quantity_requested, employee.s_name, employee.other_name, prescription.doctor_id, 
r1.strength,  -- Switched to use r1 alias
stock.unit_per_pack, stock.selling_price, stock.buying_price
FROM prescription
INNER JOIN request r1 ON prescription.medname = r1.commodity_name -- Using alias r1
INNER JOIN stock ON stock.stock_id = r1.stock_id
INNER JOIN request r2 ON r2.request_id = transaction.transaction_id  -- Using alias r2
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.employee_id = prescription.doctor_id
INNER JOIN visit ON prescription.visit_id = visit.visit_id
WHERE prescription.visit_id =  '".$id."'"
```

Note that you may need to tweak which alias is used in the above.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same alias 'request' in two joins. You need to give it a unique alias, an example of doing this is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM prescription a
INNER JOIN request b ON a.medname = b.commodity_name
INNER JOIN stock c ON c.stock_id = b.stock_id
INNER JOIN request d ...
```

Also, have you got an error in your query? You seem to be trying to join to a table called `transaction` but you don't define it in a join:

```
INNER JOIN request ON request.request_id = transaction.transaction_id
```

Should this request table actually be transaction?:

```
INNER JOIN transaction ON request.request_id = transaction.transaction_id
```